# When click the action button Map not showing

Tags: dictionary

```
.mapdisplay 
{
   position:fixed; 
   z-index:1050; 
   width:50%; 
   top:0; 
   right: 0; 
   left: 0; 
   bottom: 0; 
   overflow-x:inherit; 
   overflow-y:auto;
}
```

I have a map issue when I am clicking the button its showing popup but map not displaying first time. When minimize and maximize screen its showing.

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your api key.this issue related to api key.:)Hope this help.try to add new api key.